# Entity Framework Logical Entity Error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to have a Person entity in my model. There is no corresponding table and no discriminator. I simply want it as a common base class for some other entities to share (I want to define a `public partial class Person` with common functionality.

So, for example, I want to have:

```
// this class has no corresponding table in the DB
public partial abstract class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string DisplayName { get { return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName); } }
}

// this corresponds to dbo.Users
public partial class User : Person
{

}

// this corresponds to dbo.Contacts
public partial class Contact : Person 
{
}
```

So, I created an abstract entity Person, set it as the base class for the User and Contact entities, then added my properties, and set my mappings for dbo.Users and dbo.Contacts for the PK Id, FirstName, and LastName properties.

I get the error:

```
 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 2109
..... are being mapped to the same rows in table .... Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the `Person` entity in EDMX file and inherit both `User` and `Contact` from the `Person` in EDMX. None of properties defined in `Person` can appear in inherited entity. Then go to mapping details and map inherited entities to corresponding tables.

Be aware that primary key now must be unique for all persons - not only in derived entities.

Comment: The last statement is the problem. Since the tables have no connection, this won't be true. How can I work around this?

Comment: You don't need connection between tables you must simply ensure that they keys do not collide.

Comment: These are existing tables with tons of data each with a PK seeded at 1. How can I ensure that?

Comment: You can't and because of that you can't use inheritance unless you modify data.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Another big win for Entity Framework.